Add captions to images in carousel in SharePoint
I have an image carousel for employee photo submissions. We would like to have a caption for each photo with the photographers name and where it was taken. I do not see an option for adding a caption. I have attached a screenshot of what I see in the settings.
Does SharePoint not offer captions?

